# Comparing 2 columns in two different excel sheets and if they match copying third column

Tags: excel-formula

I have 2 different excel sheet F1 & F2. 
Sheet F1 Column A has invoice number and Column B has invoice dates
Same with sheet F2 but column E has company names.

I want to extract the company name  from sheet F2 Column E to sheet F1 Column C, only if Sheet F1 Cell A7 & B7 finds a match in sheet F2 (A6 & B6).

kk should reflect in column C row 7

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SyFnP.png]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that the Invoice number is unique, and as such a simple VlookUp formula on Column C of F1 would lookup the company name:

`=VLOOKUP(A1,'F2'!$1:$1048576,5,FALSE)`